# What is the syntax nested expressions in Watson Assistant?

Tags: watson-assistant

I'm having trouble understanding the syntax computed response text in Watson Assistant. For example the following works

```
intents = <? input.text.contains( 'intents' ) ?  intents  : 'NA' ?>
```

but does not produced the desired result which is to make "intents =" conditional as well. The obvious attempt with

```
<? input.text.contains( 'intents' ) ? 'intents =' intents : 'NA' ?>
```

does not work (and simply echos the entire expression above as text).

What am I doing wrong here? What is the syntax nested expressions in Watson Assistant?

Comment: And I am having trouble to understand your question. Where is the expression used? An example for the ternary operator is here: https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/watson-conversation-variables#conditions-and-predicates-in-the-response

Comment: @data_henrik It's used (as the question states) in the response text. The first works; the second tis not. The intent of the second is to make any output conditional (i.e., to avoid  "intents ="  when the condition is false.

Comment: So you want to overwrite "intents", the system intents or a user variable?

Comment: @data_henrik No.

Comment: If true I want to show "intents = <value of intents>", and if false I want to show NA.

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration works in the UI:

[image]

The syntax is based on [SpEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) and some is [documented specifically for WA here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods). You could write that with a [ternary operator](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/watson-conversation-variables#conditions-and-predicates-in-the-response).

The problem I had with your question is that "intents" is a reserved word. It is the variable holding the detected intents. It can be accessed in [different ways](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-expression-language).

For the ternary operator and string concatenation as expression use:

`<? intents.size() > 0 ? 'intents ='+intents : 'NA' ?>`

Comment: That's not the issue here at all; intents is being used correctly. In any case the solution it appears is simply to add `+`.

Comment: correct, I was working on that :) The string concatenation was not done